how to set runtime global var in ansible-playbook
I wanted to set the global var "file_time_stamp" with runtime value of timestamp which will used across the ansible playbook. Any information on doing this would be very useful.
I am taking backup of db and restoring in docker container in Linux_system
I am running playbook from linux_system as follow:
---
# global variables
file_time_stamp: "{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
- name: Dump db
  hosts: windows_server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ansible.windows.win_shell: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -pmy-secret-pw my_repo > C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mobile_{{ file_time_stamp }}.sql
- name: Copy the recent db dump for testing
  hosts: windows_server
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: fetch file
      fetch: src=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\mobile_{{ file_time_stamp }}.sql dest=/root/mobile_{{ file_time_stamp }}.sql flat=yes
- hosts: linux_system
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - shell: docker exec -i some-mariadb1 mysql -u root --password=my-secret-pw  --database=my_repo < /root/mobile_{{ file_time_stamp }}.sql


There are two solutions for this case.

Using set_fact

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html

This action allows setting variables associated to the current host. These variables will be available to subsequent plays during an ansible-playbook run via the host they were set on. Set cacheable to true to save variables across executions using a fact cache. Variables will keep the set_fact precedence for the current run, but will used ‘cached fact’ precedence for subsequent ones.

- name: Evaluate
  tasks:
    - set_fact: file_time_stamp="{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"

- name: Some job
  hosts: windows_server
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{file_time_stamp}} 

- name: Another job
  hosts: linux_system
  tasks:
    - shell: echo {{file_time_stamp}} 


Using group_vars

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#tips-on-where-to-set-variables

Set common defaults in a group_vars/all file.


Q: Set runtime global var in Ansible playbook.
A: Use set_fact and run_once. Quoting from Playbook Keywords:

run_once: ... apply any results and facts to all active hosts in the same batch.

For example, given nine hosts
shel> cat hosts
test_[1:9]

the below play
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
    
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        file_time_stamp: "{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
      run_once: true

creates the variable file_time_stamp in hostvars for all hosts. The below expression
  file_time_stamps: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all |
                             zip(ansible_play_hosts_all |
                                 map('extract', hostvars, 'file_time_stamp'))) }}"

gives
  file_time_stamps:
    test_1: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_2: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_3: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_4: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_5: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_6: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_7: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_8: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
    test_9: 2024-07-31_18-26-20

The hostvars are available to all plays in a playbook. For example,
- hosts: test_1

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: file_time_stamp
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.test_9.file_time_stamp

gives abridged
  file_time_stamp: 2024-07-31_18-26-20
  hostvars.test_9.file_time_stamp: 2024-07-31_18-26-20



Notes:

Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: all
    
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        file_time_stamp: "{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: all

  vars:

    file_time_stamps: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all |
                               zip(ansible_play_hosts_all |
                                   map('extract', hostvars, 'file_time_stamp'))) }}"

  tasks:
    
    - debug:
        var: file_time_stamps
      run_once: true

- hosts: test_1

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: file_time_stamp
    - debug:
        var: hostvars.test_9.file_time_stamp


Serial. The keyword run_once applies results to "all active hosts in the same batch". By default, Ansible runs in parallel against all the hosts in the pattern you set in each play's hosts: field. See Setting the batch size with serial. If you set serial and pause the tasks for one second

- hosts: all
  serial: 3
    
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        file_time_stamp: "{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
      run_once: true
    - pause:
        seconds: 1
      run_once: true

gives for example,
  file_time_stamps:
    test_1: 2024-07-31_18-48-44
    test_2: 2024-07-31_18-48-44
    test_3: 2024-07-31_18-48-44
    test_4: 2024-07-31_18-48-45
    test_5: 2024-07-31_18-48-45
    test_6: 2024-07-31_18-48-45
    test_7: 2024-07-31_18-48-46
    test_8: 2024-07-31_18-48-46
    test_9: 2024-07-31_18-48-46




If you are using a single playbook then vars section of playbook helps. something like below.
Note: The variable will be initiated at the start of playbook will continue to have same value, if you need the var to be host dependent
use in playbook
 ----
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      vars: 
        file_time_stamp: "{{ now(utc=true,fmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
      tasks:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{ file_time_stamp }}"

In case of roles, use the variable as part of defaults/main.yml in role directory and helps you to overwrite if required.
Also if the requirement is just to use timestamp ansible builtin facts can be considered. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html
"ansible_date_time": {
        "date": "2018-10-25",
        "day": "25",
        "epoch": "1540469324",
        "hour": "12",
        "iso8601": "2018-10-25T12:08:44Z",
        "iso8601_basic": "20181025T120844109754",
        "iso8601_basic_short": "20181025T120844",
        "iso8601_micro": "2018-10-25T12:08:44.109968Z",
        "minute": "08",
        "month": "10",
        "second": "44",
        "time": "12:08:44",
        "tz": "UTC",
        "tz_offset": "+0000",
        "weekday": "Thursday",
        "weekday_number": "4",
        "weeknumber": "43",
        "year": "2018"
    },

